# resize SVG Element: best practice with multiple items

Tags: svg, dart

What is the best practice for resizing say an Ellipse or Rectangle on another SVG element?

If I check for the `onMouseMove` event on the ellipse when I am out of it, the resizing stops. I was thinking to implement the listener on the `svg` element as well and pass the information to the ellipse I started the resizing on. This means having a generic `Resize()` method on the `svg` element that passes to the `Resize()` of the selected ellipse.

Isn't there an easier way?

I'm currently doing it with `Dart`, but it should be the same with `javascript`.

An example is an `<svg>` element with a `<g>` containing `<rect>` and an `<ellipse>`. If I start to resize the rectangle on a rectangle.onMouseMove, the moment I'm outside it, it stops resizing. To avoid this, I have to use the svg.onMouseMove, and use a resize method that resizes the rectangle. To know that it's the rectangle to be resized, I check for onMouseDown and again check the target (MouseEvent.target on Dart. Not sure how to detect what I'm touching without doing a cumbersome check on id maybe). Note that what I am trying to accomplish is to use the rectangle to resize the ellipse. I'm showing the rectangle only when resizing.

Comment: Hi. Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to resize an element by dragging the border of the element? Do you want to resize a group of elements at the same time, or would you like to make every element of your svg resizable separately? When do you start resizing; on mousedown?

Comment: I've added an example to make it clearer. I hope it's clear now. (I can't use ` to write html tags though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will create a circle and resize when you start dragging.
It also works when the mouse gets outside the circle.
Maybe you can modify this to your liking.

Oh, and my Dart-code might not be the best, as I just recently started learning Dart.
Any improvements are welcome.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:svg';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {

  // add new svg
  var svg = new SvgSvgElement();
  svg.style.width = '400px';
  svg.style.height = '400px';
  svg.style.border = '1px solid black';
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.append(svg);

  // add group
  var g = new SvgElement.tag('g');
  svg.append(g);

  // center of circle
  var center = new math.Point(200, 200);
  var startR = 70;
  var newR = 70;

  // add circle
  var circle = new CircleElement();
  circle.setAttribute('cx', center.x.toString());
  circle.setAttribute('cy', center.y.toString());
  circle.setAttribute('r',  startR.toString());
  circle.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
  g.append(circle);

  circle.onMouseDown.listen((MouseEvent E) {
    var startOffset = E.offset;
    var startDistance = startOffset.distanceTo(center);
    math.Point offset = E.offset;

    // now start listening for document movements so we don't need to stay on the circle
    var move = document.onMouseMove.listen((MouseEvent E) {
      // calculate new position
      var movement = E.movement;
      offset = new math.Point(
          // multiply with 0.5 to make the mouse move faster than the circle grows
          // that way we show that the mouse movement also works outside the circle element
          offset.x + movement.x * 0.5,
          offset.y + movement.y * 0.5
      );

      // calculate new distance from center
      var distance = offset.distanceTo(center);

      // calculate new radius for circle
      newR = distance / startDistance * startR;
      // resize circle
      circle.setAttribute('r', newR.toString());
    });

    // and stop all listening on mouseup
    var up = document.onMouseUp.listen(null);
    up.onData((MouseEvent E) {
      move.cancel();
      up.cancel();
      startR = newR;
    });

  });

}
```

Hope this helps,
Kind regards,
Hendrik Jan

Comment: I'm not going to accept it until I've tested it, but I hope you get a lot of votes since that document.onMouseMove inside the circle.onMouseDown is just genius! (Also that's the first time I see it on any language)

Comment: I made it a bit simpler than that, but the reasoning stands! thanks!

Comment: It can be improved though, especially if you have more events. The biggest issue I have is that I'm resizing a rectangle and checkign where I'm doing that. This means that I use a MouseMove event on that rectangle that need to be canceled but after the mouseup need to be restarted. Apparently creating a StreamSubscription isn't that easy :) (hope to be able to do it soon)